# Modularization with nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I´d like to modularize common functionality (e.g. File Uploading, Authentication + Authorization) of my web apps into single modules. This would speed up development time since these modules could be importet in a "plug n`play" kind of way.

How can this be achieved in nest js?

Answer (score 0):

This is the foundation of [Dynamic Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) and it's why you're able to just import  `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` or `JwtModule.register()` and have a database connection or JwtService ready to be consumed. If that docs page isn't enough, there's also [this good article on dynamic modules](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370)